# Windows 10 doesn't use integrated Intel graphics

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I installed Windows 10 (Enterprise) recently and everything has been working fine. I use a laptop with an Intel 3210m which has integrated Intel HD 4000 graphics. The OS is installed on an external USB hard drive.

I connected this hard drive to a different laptop which has an older 2nd gen intel cpu, with Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics. I was able to install the drivers for the older graphics by running the installer for them in Windows 8 compatability mode (the HD 3000 is not officially supported by Windows 10). I then plugged my hard drive back into the original laptop with the Intel HD 4000 and I can't use it. When I go onto the display adapter properties (right click desktop, display settings, advanced display settings), it says I am using the Microsoft Basic Display Driver (I'm pretty sure this just outsources any rendering to the CPU): [image: display adapter properties]

I have reinstalled the drivers for the HD 4000 (from Intel's website) and it shows up like this in device manager:

[image: device manager]

I'm pretty sure before that the little pci-looking chip icon that is next to the Intel HD 4000 in device manager used to be a little monitor icon (like the one next to the 'Computers' label).

I have reinstalled drivers and restarted a few times now and nothing works. I have tried completely removing the graphics drivers, rebooting and reinstalling them and I still have the same issue. I am sure that the laptop really isn't using the HD 4000 as when I try to run a very graph plotting application that uses OpenGL, the CPU usage rises to 25% (a single core's full usage) which suggests that the CPU is being used (and games use 100% cpu while running at half a frame per second). Is there any way I can fix this (I really don't want to reinstall windows).

Comment: It’s not shocking a driver designed to work with a previous model of an Intel iGPU doesn’t work with a newer model especially if you installed a Windows 8.1 driver.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not shocked at all by that. I have completely uninstalled that old HD 3000 driver and installed the correct, new HD 4000 driver (which does support windows 10), yet I cannot use the HD 4000 on the laptop.

Comment: You say that but outside of your application performance the device manager is indicating the device is functioning

Comment: @Ramhound I mentioned that I tried to play a game and it did not run at all (Dark Souls, normally runs at 25+ FPS, ran at less than 1 frame a second, also task manager was indicating it alone was using the entirety of my CPU (100%)). In addition to this, the display adapter properties indicates that the GPU is not being used as it says Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

Comment: the HD4000 is slow ad not fas enough to run games

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have been using the HD 4000 to run games for the last 5 years and have had no issues. Like I said, before these driver issues, using the HD 4000, I can run the mentioned game at 25+ FPS, whereas now it barely changes 1 frame in a second, indicating that the HD 4000 is not being put to use.

Comment: I also have this HD graphic and it is slow as hell. I have no idea how you played on it before, maybe in 1024x768 pixel with very low quality. Try [last Win10 driver for the HD4000](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/27417/a08/win64_15.33.46.4885.zip)